# Trouble upgrading jasperreports

Tags: jasper-reports

I have inherited an application and attempting to upgrade the jasperreports v. 0.6.5 to v. 3.5.3 or v. 3.6.0.  This is a J2EE application being served in on Tomcat 5.5.23 container running on linux. The application .war file is compiled using Maven.

Here is what I have tried so far:

- Recompiled all .jrxml files on a Windows XP machine that has used previous versions of jasperreports (1.2.1 to 3.6.0) using iReport.
- Recompiled all .jrxml files on another Windows XP machine that has never used previous versions of jasperreports using iReport.
- Recompiled all .jrxml files on a Linux machine that has never used previous versions of jasperreports using iReport.
- Cleared out the contents of the $TOMCAT_HOME/webapp directory. 
  With my many attempts, the reports will not run inside the application, and the following error is produced in the log file:
- Updated the version of java on the testing machine to the exact version of java that was used to build the application .war file.

What else can I try with this?

Here is the stack:

*java.io.InvalidClassException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseReport; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 10200, local class serialVersionUID = 605
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:546)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1552)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1466)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1552)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1466)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1699)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1305)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:348)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:86)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:162)
        at tahc.hris.webapp.action.GenerateReport.execute(GenerateReport.java:127)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at tahc.hris.webapp.filter.ActionFilter.doFilter(ActionFilter.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:151)
        at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:200)
        at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:283)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:773)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:703)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:895)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:685)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
NESTED BY :
java.io.InvalidClassException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseReport; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 10200, local class serialVersionUID = 605
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:546)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1552)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1466)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1552)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1466)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1699)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1305)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:348)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:86)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:162)
        at tahc.hris.webapp.action.GenerateReport.execute(GenerateReport.java:127)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at tahc.hris.webapp.filter.ActionFilter.doFilter(ActionFilter.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:151)
        at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:200)
        at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:283)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:773)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:703)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:895)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:685)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
NESTED BY :
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error loading object from file : /usr/local/tomcat5/webapps/.../*.jasper
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:90)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:162)
        at tahc.hris.webapp.action.GenerateReport.execute(GenerateReport.java:127)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
        at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
        at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at tahc.hris.webapp.filter.ActionFilter.doFilter(ActionFilter.java:91)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:525)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:151)
        at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:200)
        at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:283)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:773)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:703)
        at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:895)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:685)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.base.JRBaseReport; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 10200, local class serialVersionUID = 605
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:546)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1552)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1466)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1552)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1466)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1699)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1305)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:348)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:86)
        ... 27 more*

Answer (score 1):

sallam ,

i have the same exception that you got, what i did first was to take the sample of webapp of
jasperreports 3.7.6 and make it run.

two ways to do so:
1.1 use the ant commands (*) then create the jasper-webapp.war and put it in ..\tomcat.6.0\webapps\ folder 
* http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/getting.started.html

1.2 create a new project using an IDE like intellij then copy all the webapp sample folder to it. then attach the ant to build.xml file in this folder. after that run the ant and compile/run the project.

1. open the browser in localhost:[port] then you can see Web Application Sample
   first goto applet viewr in left menu and follow this link:
   "click here to test whether your browser can run Swing applets or not" 
   if you could run it and see applet rectangle then you have no problem if not try to open these pages above using another browser like "google chroom" , he might want to download the java from internet just follow the steps.
2. after running the test goto home page of this sample and follow the pages by this order compile JRXML ,  fill report, then click the Embedded Viewer Applet link in "applet viewer" 
   page and see if it running correctly.
3. try to understand the sample and take a look at the applet folder (inside the webapp sample) you can see three jars: 
   jasperreports-applet-3.7.6.jar,commons-logging-1.0.4.jar,commons-collections-2.1.1.jar

open the viewer.html and see how sample is using this jars and calling the "EmbeddedViewerApplet.class" throw javascript.

1. in the servlet, write the report data to a pdf file on the server and then from the applet get a handle to the applet context object and invoke the showDocument method passing the path where I saved the pdf file. 
   taken from: http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=1291

i hope this can help sombody ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to copy the Jasper*.jar files from iReport to your application Lib folder. You might be running using a different library than the one of compiling.